# How to display a single page of a multi-document PDF pages using SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, webview, swift3

I want to display a single page for a chosen PDF file even if the PDF has more than one page.

So that only a single PDF page is displayed according to the selected page number.

I am writing this code:

```
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "PDFName", ofType: "pdf")!)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: path as URL)
    webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
```

But that displays all pages of a document.
I want to show only one page by page number?

Comment: use UIDocumentInteractViewController for your concept

Comment: I looked for this I did not find the solution. Is there an example or explanation that can help me do.I am working on the UIPageViewController application and I would like to add a PDF file so that all the pages are displayed in a separate page. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for step by step implementation , you can get the tutorial [here1](https://ayeohyes.wordpress.com/tag/uidocumentinteractioncontroller/) and [here2](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130)

```
class ReaderViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

 func loadDocUsingDocInteractionController() {

if let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PDFName", ofType: "pdf") { // Use if let to unwrap to fileURL variable if file exists
    let docInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL)!)
    docInteractionController.delegate = self
    docInteractionController.presentPreviewAnimated(true)
}
}

// Return the view controller from which the    UIDocumentInteractionController will present itself.
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -&gt; UIViewController {
return self
}
```

**swift3**

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
```

and call the function as like

```
@IBAction func btnOpenModal(_ sender: UIButton) {

  //  var button: UIButton? = (sender as? UIButton)
    let URLName: URL? = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "pdf")
    if URLName != nil {
        // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
        let  documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URLName!)
        // Configure Document Interaction Controller
        documentInteractionController.delegate = self
        // Present Open In Menu
        documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: sender .frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
    }
}

func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {

    return self
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now you can display the page number 4 for example an independent in ViewControllero of PDF file contains a 20 pages?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me to reach this project and that work good. https://github.com/ILearniOS/PDF-Reader